# Gateway operator to sub-flow stops processing

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I've faced a problem with sub-flows in Spring Integration.
According to documentation ([1](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-gateway), [2](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/chain.html#chain-gateway)) I can create a do something like this:

```
@Bean
fun calculateAndSafeFlow(): IntegrationFlow =
    integrationFlow("calculateAndSaveChannel") {
        handle(prepareDataResolver)
        gateway("calculateChannel")
        handle(calculationResultPersistor)
    }

@Bean
fun calculateFlow(): IntegrationFlow =
    integrationFlow("calculateChannel") {
        handle(calculationHandler)
    }
```

Basiclly, I need one flow for just a calculation and second for calculation and storing the results.
My problem is on line with `gateway()` operator. On this line it just stops processing. The calculationFlow does not take a control and nothing happens.
Calculation handler always returns a result.
Maybe I missed something... Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

When you do a `gateway()`, then it means the reply must comes back from that call. So, apparently your `handle(calculationHandler)` does not return. Show us what your `calculationHandler` is doing and fix it the way it can return something which will be treated as a reply and then it will be sent back to the `replyChannel` header initiated by that `gateway()`.

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply.  
In a code above I removed `log()` operator on the start and finish of `calculationFlow`. After I remove `log()` operator on the end of the flow, the problem was solved.
@ArtemBilan, can you, please, explain me, why `log()` operator does not return a message in the end of the flow?

Comment: See docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-log. In two words: in previous version the `log()` behavior was inconsistent and it was treated as terminal operator when it was used in the end of the flow without any reply producing attempts. If you would migrate to Spring Integration `6.0`, it would work as you'd expected. So, you see: you are not the first who bumped to this problem and we have listened and changed our vision and have made this API transparent as possible.